# Why can't I set the attributes of client.intents?

Tags: python, discord.py

I try to write a discord bot and had some issues getting the list of users connected to a voice channel. I was told to set the intents. So I read [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#intents) and wrote this bit of code:

```py
client = discord.Client()
client.intents.members = True
client.intents.presences = True
print_intents()
```

The print_intents method is one I made myself and it does what the name suggests, it prints the values of all attributes of the client.intents object. This outputs the following:

```
bans: True
dm_messages: True
dm_reactions: True
dm_typing: True
emojis: True
guild_messages: True
guild_reactions: True
guild_typing: True
guilds: True
integrations: True
invites: True
members: False
messages: True
presences: False
reactions: True
typing: True
value: 32509
voice_states: True
webhooks: True
```

This matches the default settings of Intents as returned by its default method. The two values I wanted changed still have their default values. I don't understand why that's the case. In the documentation it says:

> Similar to Permissions, the properties provided are two way. You can set and retrieve individual bits using the properties as if they were regular bools.

Comment: Try using `discord.Intents.all()`?

Comment: I have tried to use it but I'm unsure about how it works. Just calling the method on the object does nothing and trying to set client.intents = discord.Intents.all() or client.intents = client.intents.all() gives me an error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute `client.intents` must be of the `discord.Intents` class. They cannot be assigned the way you have done it. (According to documents, it must be of type `discord.Intents`).
See [`discord.Intents`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents) docs.

You should use `discord.Intents.all()` as it will define all intents as `True`. The `.default()` removes only the ones you want. `.all()` won't.

The best way to do this is during initialization.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # You can use this
# OR create Intents and manually change the values
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```